# sed is not working from inside bash

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I'm trying to use sed to replace ${SRC} and ${MSG} from external files. Both of them are variables that are available in following bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

SRC=$1
DST=$2
MSG=$3
CONN=$4
GROUP=$5


echo "$SRC","$DST","$MSG","$CONN","$GROUP" >> /home/maaz/smpp/smppin/incoming.log

/usr/bin/sed -i -e "s/\${SRC}/$SRC/" -e "s/\${MSG}/$MSG/" request.xml >> request.xml
```

File request.xml looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:SendSMS>
        <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:Number>${SRC}</tem:Number>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:AccountID>${MSG}</tem:AccountID>
      </tem:SendSMS>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to replace text ${SRC} and ${MSG} with their corresponding values from bash. At the moment same sed expression is replacing text,if running from outside bash, but no change in file when script is called.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: If you use `-i` with `sed`, it automatically edits the file in-place. Redirecting the output from a file which is also input will usually leave you with an empty file. Just drop `>>request.xml` from the end.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, it's `>>` not `>` So, OP will probably not be left with empty file. Plus, since this command does not produce any `stdout` (because of `-i`) this would probably work, although it is wrong way....

Comment: @AndrasDeak, `-i` isn't part of the POSIX standard for `sed`, and not all operating systems and implementations provide it. Moreover, not all implementations are compatible -- `sed -i -e 'expression' filename` works on GNU sed, but not MacOS sed, which requires `-i` to be followed by a filename extension to append to a backup (optional in the GNU version).

Comment: BTW -- editing xml with sed is very, **very** much frowned on -- you can trivially end up with a corrupt output file when your input file or the content to be substituted change in minor ways. There's no shortage of questions and answers in the knowledge base on how to do it correctly, so I won't overmuch belabor the point.

Comment: Your script is very fragile - you need to quote `$1`...`$5` in your initial examples, for example, and you'll need to escape `/` that you're using as separator for sed's `s` command when expanding the replacement (e.g. `sed -e s/'${SRC}'/"${SRC//\//\\/}"/`).  As well as dropping the `-i` flag, of course.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm considering unfollowing [bash] to spare some work for you;) Thanks for the correction once again.

Comment: @TobySpeight, actually, string-splitting and glob expansion are disabled on assignments, so the OP is safe without quoting there. You're right, though, that the `sed` code is fragile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring that your input file is XML, `envsubst` is the right tool for substituting placeholders of the form `${foo}` with values in an environment variable of that same name.

```
src=$1; dst=$2; msg=$3; conn=$4; group=$5
tempfile=$(mktemp -t request.xml.XXXXXX)

# to edit request.xml in-place:
SRC=$src DST=$dst MSG=$msg CONN=$conn GROUP=$group envsubst \
  <request.xml >"$tempfile" && mv "$tempfile" request.xml
```

---

That said, if we *didn't* ignore that, and chose to use XML-aware tools, we'd come up with an altogether different solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
SRC=hello
MSG=world
tempfile=$(mktemp request.xml.XXXXXX)
xmlstarlet ed -u '//*[.="${SRC}"]' -v "$SRC" \
              -u '//*[.="${MSG}"]' -v "$MSG" \
  <request.xml >"$tempfile" && mv "$tempfile" request.xml
```

...yields, given your input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <tem:SendSMS>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <tem:Number>hello</tem:Number>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <tem:AccountID>world</tem:AccountID>
    </tem:SendSMS>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

...and is guaranteed to result in output that's in valid XML format, even if the strings to be substituted need to be escaped or otherwise modified to be valid in XML.

Comment: Nice. but is there reason for exporting the variables in your first method?

Comment: @sjsam, otherwise they aren't accessible to `envsubst`, which -- as the name implies -- pulls from the environment.

Comment: Okay. but exporting might not be desirable iMHO as in the case of collision with preexisting variables.

Comment: @sjsam, if there are preexisting environment variables with the same names, simply setting those shell variables with the same names will overwrite them as it is. The moment the OP decided to use all-upper-case variable names they made that bug unavoidable.

Comment: @sjsam, ...bug now avoided -- we're now using lower-case variable names, and only exporting upper-case ones for the duration of the `envsubst` command.

Answer (score 0):

Below script will do:

```
dst=$2 # Uppercase variables are usually reserved for the system
msg=$3 # So use lowercase variables for your scripts like 'dst','msg' and so
.
.
.
sed -E -i 's/\$\{SRC\}/'"$src"'/g;s/\$\{MSG\}/'"$msg"'/g' request.xml
```

**Notes**

1. The inplace edit option `-i` makes the change effective in the file.
2. You should never do `request.xml >> request.xml` ie read from and write to the file simultaneously
3. There is no harm in double quoting the variables (eg `SRC="$1"`). This will prevent word splitting in the variables.
4. The `-E` option with sed is more portable and recognized with most of the sed versions these days.

**Edit**
If extended regular expressions are not enabled, you could write the sed statement like below :

```
sed -i 's/\${SRC}/'"$src"'/g;s/\${MSG}/'"$msg"'/g' request.xml
```

Comment: Huh? `-e` and `-E` do two entirely different things; there's no question of one being a more/less portable alternative for the other.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : I was not having `-e` in mind . In fact I was having the `-r` option in mind when I typed that statement. I put that because not all sed manpages have the `E` option listed though they support it,, In this case, I now feel, it would have been easier not to enable extended regex because that involved a lot of escaping the `{}`.

Comment: Ahh. Indeed, I read the context wrong re: the "`-E` option [...] is more portable" bullet point. (To be fair, saying *what* it's more portable than would make misparses less likely).

Answer (score 0):

Check if sed path `/usr/bin/sed` on your system.
It's `/bin/sed` on mine.

Comment: I don' have permissions yet to make comments to questions.

Comment: Sorry about that pal.. Retracted the downvote.. But there are a couple more issues to address in the OP's script..

Comment: Anyhow, the OP says that there's no change in the file, not that they're getting a "file not found" error.